# Data structure manager implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am a beginner Java developer, and I am self learning Java by developing a real life [business desktop application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_software) intended for management in repair shops. It is unimaginatively called [**Repair Shop Software**](https://github.com/EmperorZoran/Repair-Shop-Software). You can see the whole project on GitHub [**here**](https://github.com/EmperorZoran/Repair-Shop-Software). I just wanted an opinion on my data-structure management class **`DataManager`**. I have a filing I am doing some sort of anti-pattern int this class but I don't know because I am just a beginner. I use the same principle in my [**`ComboBoxModelManager`**](https://github.com/EmperorZoran/Repair-Shop-Software/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yankov/repair_shop/app/utility/ComboBoxModelManager.java) class.

**`DataManager` class:**

```
public class DataManager
{   
    public static IndexedData notificationsDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData notificationTypesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData servicesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData serviceTypesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData ticketsDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData statusTypesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData clientsDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData marketingTypesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData legalEntitiesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData devicesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData modelsDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData deviceTypesDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData brandsDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();
    public static IndexedData usersDataTable = new IndexedDataTable();

    private static final HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData> dataTables = new HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData>();

    static
    {
        dataTables.put(EntityType.NOTIFICATION, notificationsDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.NOTIFICATION_TYPE, notificationTypesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.SERVICE, servicesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.SERVICE_TYPE, serviceTypesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.TICKET, ticketsDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.STATUS, statusTypesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.CLIENT, clientsDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.MARKETING, marketingTypesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.LEGAL_ENTITY, legalEntitiesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.DEVICE, devicesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.MODEL, modelsDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.DEVICE_TYPE, deviceTypesDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.BRAND, brandsDataTable);
        dataTables.put(EntityType.USER, usersDataTable);
    }

    public static IndexedData getDataTable(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return dataTables.get(entityType);
    }

    public static Entity getEntity(EntityType entityType, int id)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).getEntity(id);
    }

    public static Entity getEntity(EntityType entityType, String name)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).getEntity(name);
    }

    public static int getEntityCounter(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).getEntityCounter();
    }

    public static HashMap<Integer, Entity>getIdMap(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).getIdMap();
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Entity> getDisplayNameMap(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).getDisplayNameMap();
    }

    public static boolean isDataTableEmpty(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return getEntityCounter(entityType) == 0;
    }

    public static boolean idCollision(EntityType entityType, int id)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).idCollision(id);
    }

    public static boolean displayNameCollision(EntityType entityType, String displayName)
    {
        return getDataTable(entityType).displayNameCollision(displayName);
    }

    public static void save(Entity newEntity)
    {
        getDataTable(newEntity.getEntityType()).save(newEntity);

        ComboBoxModelManager.updateModel(newEntity);
    }

    public static void delete(Entity newEntity)
    {
        getDataTable(newEntity.getEntityType()).delete(newEntity);
    }

    public static void resetTicketCounter()
    {
        ticketsDataTable.resetEntityCounter();
    }
}
```

**To make things more clearer this is the `IndexedDataTable` class - it is basically a in-memory representation of a database table.**

```
public class IndexedDataTable implements IndexedData
{
    private int entityCounter = 0;
    private HashMap<Integer, Entity> idMap = new HashMap<Integer, Entity>();
    private HashMap<String, Entity> displayNameMap = new HashMap<String, Entity>();

    @Override
    public int getEntityCounter()
    {
        return entityCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void resetEntityCounter()
    {
        entityCounter =0;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<Integer, Entity> getIdMap()
    {
        return idMap;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Entity> getDisplayNameMap()
    {
        return displayNameMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Entity getEntity(int id)
    {
        return idMap.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Entity getEntity(String displayName)
    {
        return displayNameMap.get(displayName);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean idCollision(int id)
    {
        return idMap.containsKey(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean displayNameCollision(String displayName)
    {
        return displayNameMap.containsKey(displayName);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Entity newEntity)
    {
        entityCounter++;

        idMap.put(newEntity.getId(), newEntity);

        if(EntityType.hasDisplayName(newEntity))
        {
            displayNameMap.put(newEntity.getDisplayName(), newEntity);
        }

        if(EntityType.makesReferences(newEntity))
        {
            newEntity.createReferences();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Entity newEntity)
    {
        idMap.remove(newEntity.getId());

        if(EntityType.hasDisplayName(newEntity))
        {
            displayNameMap.remove(newEntity.getDisplayName());
        }

        if(EntityType.makesReferences(newEntity))
        {
            newEntity.deleteReferences();
        }
    }
}
```

**And also for clarity's sake this is the enumeration class `EntityType` that is used for [polymorphism](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-polymorphism/) of this and other classes in my project.**

```
public enum EntityType
{
    NOTIFICATION,
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE,
    SERVICE,
    SERVICE_TYPE,
    TICKET,
    STATUS,
    CLIENT,
    MARKETING,
    LEGAL_ENTITY,
    DEVICE,
    MODEL,
    DEVICE_TYPE,
    BRAND,
    USER;

    public static boolean hasDisplayName(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return !(entityType == NOTIFICATION
              || entityType == SERVICE
              || entityType == TICKET
              || entityType == DEVICE);
    }

    public static boolean hasDisplayName(Entity entity)
    {
        return hasDisplayName(entity.getEntityType());
    }



    public static boolean makesReferences(Entity entity)
    {
        EntityType dataType = entity.getEntityType();

        return (dataType == NOTIFICATION)
            || (dataType == SERVICE)
            || (dataType == TICKET)
            || (dataType == CLIENT)
            || (dataType == DEVICE)
            || (dataType == MODEL);
    }

    public static boolean isAProperty(EntityType dataType)
    {
        return (dataType == NOTIFICATION_TYPE)
            || (dataType == MARKETING)
            || (dataType == STATUS)
            || (dataType == DEVICE_TYPE)
            || (dataType == BRAND);
    }
}
```

**And also if anyone has the time to review my whole project, and give my some advice on what an I am doing wrong, and what a I am doing right, I would be very grateful. [Link to my project on GitHub](https://github.com/EmperorZoran/Repair-Shop-Software).**

***PS: I don't really know is this a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some general recommendation for your code.

**1) When using collections, I suggest that you use the interface instead of the implementation in the left part. It will be easier when refactoring and if you want to change the implementation.**

*Before*

```java
private static final HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData> dataTables = new HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData>();
```

*After*

```java
private static final Map<EntityType, IndexedData> dataTables = new HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData>();
```

**2) Instead of using the `java.util.HashMap` implementation with `Enum` as a key, I suggest that you use the `java.util.EnumMap` implementation instead.**

**[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html)**

> Implementation note: All basic operations execute in constant time. They are likely (though not guaranteed) to be faster than their HashMap counterparts.

*Example*

```java
    private static final Map<EntityType, IndexedData> dataTables = new EnumMap<>(EntityType.class);
```

**3) The constant should be all uppercase with words separated by underscores ("_"); it's a naming convention, not required, but highly recommended.**

*Before*

```java
    private static final HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData> dataTables = new HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData>();
```

*After*

```java
    private static final HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData> DATA_TABLES = new HashMap<EntityType, IndexedData>();
```

**4) When comparing `Enum` with else-if, I suggest that you use a Switch-case instead; since the switch case can be faster than the if-else in some cases**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705955/why-switch-is-faster-than-if
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287700/difference-between-jvms-lookupswitch-and-tableswitch

Also, in my opinion, it makes the code more readable and easier to refactor.

*Before*

```java
    public static boolean hasDisplayName(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return !(entityType == NOTIFICATION
                || entityType == SERVICE
                || entityType == TICKET
                || entityType == DEVICE);
    }
```

*After*

```java
    public static boolean hasDisplayName(EntityType entityType)
    {
        switch (entityType)
        {
            case NOTIFICATION:
            case SERVICE:
            case TICKET:
            case DEVICE:
                return false;

            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code-style review of my code, I will implement your suggestions immediately. Regarding my main question , the pattern I used for this `DataManager` class, can you please comment on it, is it a stupid way for managing data or not?

Comment: In my opinion, the data structure used is fine, I see no issues there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had pull that design pattern out of my ass, as I did 'not how to implement data structure manager. So I was worried it was some anti-pattern.